# Prolog | Remove sub-list from List

Tags: prolog

New to Prolog,
I am trying to remove a sublist from a list and return the result, I feel like I am close but it is not working.

```
    remove_sublist([],[],[]).
    remove_sublist(Lst,Sub,Ret):-
        Lst = [H|T], Ret = [H1|T1],
        (/+member(H,Sub)
        ->H1 is H, remove_sublist(T,Sub,Ret)
        ;remove_sublist(T,Sub,Ret)).
```

For example when I input the query I want it to output as follows:

```
    ?- remove_sublist([1,2,3,4,5,6],[2,4,6],X).
    X = [1,3,5].
```

Not sure where to go from here I have deleted and re-written code for a few hours...

Edit/Update:
I changed the base case from:

```
    remove_sublist([],[],[]).
```

to

```
    remove_sublist([],Sub,Ret).
```

and now it outputs this: X = [1,3,5,_11996|_11998].
Anyone know how to get rid of the anonymous variables there?

Comment: `/+member(H,Sub)` is really weird. Do you mean `\+member(H,Sub)`? Should really just be `member(H,Sub)` (and reverse the consequents), it is always more efficient to prove a positive than to try to make sure no positive exists.

Comment: Evidently you are trying to write an imperative program. What you actually have to do is write a predicate that makes sure that there is a certain relation between its arguments, in this case, the list named `Ret` contains all the members of `Lst` except thos that can be found in `Sub`. You just the predicate `member/2`, the "make sure it's equal" predicate `=`, list assemble/disassemble `[H|T]` and a recursive call. Forget about `\+` and `->` and `is` (which is "arithmetic eval of the right-hand side). The base case `remove_sublist([],Sub,Ret).` is correct; you stop the recursion once Lst=[].

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing predicate, subtract. Example of use:

```
subtract([1,2,3,4],[1,2],Z).
```

Simple solution using the findall predicate:

```
remove_sublist(Lst,Sub,Z):-
    findall(X,
           (member(X, Lst), not(member(X, Sub))),
            Z).
```

Another solution.
If you want a recursive implementation:

```
remove_sublist([],_,[]).

remove_sublist([H|T],S,Z):-
    remove_sublist(T, S, Z1),
    (member(H,S) -> Z = Z1 ; Z = [H|Z1]).
```